# remove dir and .php from the url

Tags: php, apache

My url is below.

http://192.168.43.173/My/tree/admin/city/city.php

I am trying to rewrite it like below.

http://192.168.43.173/My/tree/admin/cities

I wrote below code in my php directory by creating the .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\city/city.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}cities [L]
```

Above did not work. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

this will fetch URLs that ends with `city/city.php` and redirect 301 to `cities`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/city/city.php
RewriteRule (.*)/city/city.php$ $1/cities [R=301, L]
```

Comment: this is my url - http://192.168.43.173/My/tree/admin/city/city.php I want to keep admin in url. But, the code above is not working.